# SQL Server & XML: how can I get an xml attribute from sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table like this:

```
create table product 
(
    id integer, 
    category varchar(50), 
    quantity integer, 
    techdata varchar(100), 
    cost_price float
);

insert into product 
values (1, 'window', 2, '<Data w="1000" h="1000"/>', 100.56),
       (2, 'door', 1, '<Data w="900" h="1800"/>', 96.12),
       (3, 'window', 20, '<Data w="750" h="300"/>', 152.5),
       (4, 'door', 100, '<Data w="1046" h="2046"/>', 46.74),
       (5, 'window', 1, null, null);
```

I have to select all 'w' and 'h' attribute values from those rows. I've tried this solution but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    t.p.value('(@w)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS width,
    t.p.value('(@h)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS height
FROM 
    product 
CROSS APPLY 
    techdata.nodes('/Data') t(p)
```

Any hint for proper solution?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem. You get error  or bad results ? What results do you expect ?

Comment: "The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml." - that's the error which I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that the column techdata is not XML type.

Try this

```
select
    CONVERT(xml, techdata).value('(/Data/@w)[1]', 'int') as Width,
    CONVERT(xml, techdata).value('(/Data/@h)[1]', 'int') as Height
from product
```

Comment: It works - You're right, column is varchar not xml, so it must be converted to proper data type.  Thank's a lot!